# Extract Dictionary Values from Classifier Output

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, text-classification

I'm trying zero-shot classification. I get an output like below

```
[{'labels': ['rep_appreciation',
   'cx_service_appreciation',
   'issue_resolved',
   'recommend_product',
   'callback_realted',
   'billing_payment_related',
   'disppointed_product'],
  'scores': [0.9198898673057556,
   0.8672246932983398,
   0.79215407371521,
   0.6239275336265564,
   0.4782547056674957,
   0.39024001359939575,
   0.010263209231197834],
  'sequence': 'Alan Edwards provided me with nothing less the excellent assistance'}
```

Above is output for one row in a data frame

I'm hoping to finally build a data frame columns and output values mapped like below. 1s for labels if the scores are above certain threshold

[image: output sample]

Any nudge/help to solve this is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a function which returns a key : value dictionary for every row, with key being the label and value being 1/0 based on threshold

```
def get_label_score_dict(row, threshold):
    result_dict = dict()
    for _label, _score in zip(row['labels'], row['scores']):
        if _score > threshold:
            result_dict.update({_label: 1})
        else:
            result_dict.update({_label: 0})
    return result_dict
```

Now if you have a *list_of_rows* with each row being in the form as shown above, then you can use the *map* function to get the above mentioned dictionary for every row. Once you get this, convert it into a DataFrame.

```
th = 0.5    #whatever threshold value you want
result = list(map(lambda x: get_label_score_dict(x, th), list_of_rows))
result_df = pd.DataFrame(result)
```

Comment: awesome, thanks!. works as intended. Appreciate your help